# Statement of Kufr

Tags: shirk, kufr

Assalamu Alaikum
I wanted to know if this constitutes as kufr or not. My Baby cosuin was wearing a shirt on which was written “Good looks , courtesy of Daddy” . I know that the looks of a person are made by Allah and this is shirk but When his mother jokingly said “no courtest of mommy” I also jokingly said no “It is written courtesy of daddy”. Does this act alone constitue kufr even though I no intention of endorsing anything like this but just said what was written.

Answer (score -1):

**Bismillah Hir Rahmaan Nir Raheem**

**As Salaamu 3laykum,**

I hope you are doing well. At this point I would like to present to you a hadith

"I remember that the Messenger of ALLAH (Peace Be Upon Him) said: 'Leave what makes you in doubt for what does not make you in doubt. The truth brings tranquility while falsehood sows doubt.'" (Tirmidhi)

In this place I would say the shahadah again to be safe. In my opinion I would be more inclined that the person say the shahadah (testimony of faith) again. Because yes your looks are not in our control. I am just talking aloud right now, like we say that this food gave me the strength today to do my work. Of course we are not attributing ALLAH (Glory Be To Him) with the food. We understand that ALLAH (Glory Be To Him) gave the power to that food to do its things for us in our bodies to give us that strength. However, with looks its not in our hands at all. So how could we say thank you to our parents for our looks when ALLAH (Glory Be To Him) didn't give that power to them.

From the hadith that our looks are not in our control comes from the following:

Narrated by al-Bukhaari (5943) and Muslim (2125) from Ibn Mas‘ood (may ALLAH be pleased with him) who said: "May ALLAH curse the one who does tattoos and the one who has a tattoo done, the one who plucks eyebrows and the one who has her eyebrows plucked, and those who file teeth for the purpose of beautification, changing the creation of ALLAH."

So our permanent creation has come from ALLAH (Glory Be To HIM). We should never do permanent changes.

**Have a nice day!**

**Wa 3laykum As Salaam**